# Python Selenium Editing starred out password field

Tags: python, selenium

Have a few issues clicking on a password field for my router web interface page. Below are 2 examples.

A: I get no errors, however the password field does not become show the password like when I manually click

B: I get a element not clickable or with a slight change element not interactable

My question is what am I missing here.
Below is the elements from the page

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="password" id="wrlPwd" name="wrlPwd" class="validatebox input-large" maxlength="63" data-options="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;ssidPwd&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[8,63]}">
</div>
```

And below the 2 parts of code

A: `PsWrD = browser.find_element_by_class_name('control-label')`

B: `PsWrD = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="id="wrlPwd"" and @class="controls"]') browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", PsWrD)`

The goal is not to view the password but highlight the text field to change the password. I attempted a few other things such as css and name. I am able to navigate every where else but I am stuck on this little bit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was my HTML Knowledge. The issue was my element was in an iframe and so could not find it. To resolve I used:

````
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"membeeLoginIF")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.textboxWaterMark#txtUserName"))).send_keys("Jeff")```
````

Once I switched to the iframe i found it with out issue

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to click is

```
<input type="password" id="wrlPwd" name="wrlPwd" class="validatebox input-large" ...>
```

Always start with ID or name, if they are available. This one has both so lets use ID

```
browser.find_element_by_id("wrlPwd").click()
```

The locators you are using are not correct.

A: There is no class, `control-label`, on the INPUT element you posted. The class is `class="validatebox input-large"` and the classes are `validatebox` and `input-large`.

B: Same problem with this one... you are confusing elements or something. The XPath you are using, `//div[@id="id="wrlPwd"" and @class="controls"]` has a couple issues.

1. You've mangled the id in there twice, `@id="id="wrlPwd""`, which should have thrown an invalid XPath error, and the DIV does not have that ID, the INPUT does.
2. The second part, `and @class="controls"`, is correct for the DIV but you want to click the INPUT.

Additionally, you may want to add a `WebDriverWait` to wait for the INPUT to be clickable if there are timing issues. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I probably need to go back and brush up on my html. I did throw in a ` PsWrD = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "wrlPwd")))
PsWrD.click()`  However it times out. I think from not finding it. I will through a few more attempts around what you have said. Many thanks